# Transfer function and graphic (Scilab error)

Tags: simulation, transfer-function, matrix, state-space

I'm trying to solve this problem with a Scilab code:

[image]

I'm trying to follow this code, but in the step `[b,a]=ss2tf[A,B,C,D]`, it shows the error ("Wrong number of input arguments.")
The code of Scilab that I try to make is the following:

```
clc; 
clear all;
close all;
A=[-1 -2;42 -0.9]
B=[1.5;1.1]
C=[0.7 2.1]
D=[0]
[b,a]=ss2tf(A,B,C,D)
H=tf(b,a)
figure
step(H)
grid
```

How can I fix this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to point this out, but it seems that you are using the Matlab notation and have not even looked at the Scilab language reference, still,

```
clc; 
clear all;
xdel(winsid())

A=[-1 -2;42 -0.9]
B=[1.5;1.1]
C=[0.7 2.1]
D=[0]
H=syslin('c',A,B,C,D)
H=ss2tf(H)
figure
t=0:0.05:5;
plot(t,csim('step',t,H))
xgrid(2)
```